# rails- updating form redirecting to the wrong page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a form to update the user's details, however, they are called customers and have a customers controller. 
Making changes and updating the form works but it redirects to /user/1 instead of /customer/1/

Form, should this be @user or @customer ?

```
 <divclass="form-group">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :firstname, "Name:", class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    </br>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: "form-control"  %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone1, "Phone:", class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    </br>
 <%= f.text_field :phone1, class: "form-control" %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Controller

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # match '/customers/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @users = User.where(id: params[:id])
  end


  def new
      @users = User.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
   def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @driver }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def set_customer
      @customer = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:title, :firstname, :lastname, :billing_address, :billing_postcode, :delivery_address, :delivery_postcode, :phone1, :phone2, :notes)
    end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



    get 'customers/index'
    get 'customers/new'
    get 'customers/delete'
    get 'customers/edit'

  end



  resources :vans
  resources :customers do
  # resources :orders
end
  devise_for :users
  # Change get method for user signout
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end



  root 'pages#index'

  resources :categories
  resources :products, only: [:show]
  resources :drivers
  resources :product_items
  resources :baskets
  resources :orders
  resources :customers
  resources :taxes
  resources :users
```

This is probably really simple but I can't seem to work it out. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

This line sends the form to UsersController if the @user hasn't yet an id then it'll be send it to create method, if the @user has an id which means it already exists at db then it'll be send it to update method

The answer to your question yes you should create a form_for @customer if what you want is send the form CustomersController

```
    <%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
```

NOTE: @customer must exist at your new method

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Could i just set up a redirect for any /user/1 to point to customer/1 or would this be bad in the long run?

Comment: at your customers_controller.rb you are creating users which don't make sense. If you want to send the data to CustomerController then create a form_for customer.